# traversing dom elements for right jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following html snippet, I cant seem to access the input elements under the div with class="input-group"

```
 <form action="login.html#register" method="post" id="form-register" class="form-horizontal display-none">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="gi gi-user"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" id="register-firstname" name="register-firstname" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Firstname">
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-6">
               <input type="text" id="register-lastname" name="register-lastname" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Lastname">
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-xs-12">
               <div class="input-group">
                   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="gi gi-envelope"></i></span>
                   <input type="text" id="register-email" name="register-email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email">
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

I have tried numerous selector syntax but nothing seems to work. I cannot figure out why this version  doesn't work, it certainly should, but I'm no expert on JQuery just yet.
To me the syntax below says get all the items with class form-group in the element with id form-register, then get all divs with class input-group and then all the input tags in those divs. Am I mistaken there?

```
 $('#form-register.form-group > div.input-group > input').attr('disabled', true);
```

The proper syntax is, via assistance from the accepted answer;

```
 $('#form-register div[class^="col-xs"] input').attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work, neither does anything else which is why im sure the selector syntax is worng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS syntax is incorrect. Try this:

```
$('#form-register .form-group div.input-group > input').attr('disabled', true);
```

Firstly, notice the space between the first two selectors, because `.form-group` is a child of `#form-register`. Secondly the `>` means 'direct child of', so was incorrect when used on `div.input-group`.

Comment: ty, that does work but doesnt disable the lastname input which isnt a direct child of input group, how do I handle that?

Comment: I guess i can use div[class^="col-xs"] ?

Comment: That's because the lastname field is not a child of a `.input-group` element. Remove that selector if needed: `$('#form-register .form-group input')`.

Comment: $('#form-register div[class^="col-xs"] input').attr('disabled', true); works beautifully, thank you for the assistance